# Angularjs : Is there any way to use list of functions as filter expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I want to have 1 function for each column in my table directive and each function will be changed at runtime. Columns type and number of columns may vary.

Each column Filter can be -

- list of alphabets to choose from
- date picker
- list of unique values of related column
- others...

I created a property to be used for all columns' filters in directive template as following

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter : columnFilters | filter: search | orderBy: sortBy: reverse">
```

Is there any way to use list of functions in either of following way as filter expressions?

```js
$scope.columnFilters = [
    function() { /* Logic 1 */ },
    function() { /* Logic 2 */ },
    function() { /* Logic N */ }
];

// OR

$scope.columnFilters = {
    column1 : function() { /* Logic for column 1 */ },
    column2 : function() { /* Logic for column 2 */ },
    columnN : function() { /* Logic for column N */ },
};
```

As per [AngularJS filter API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) we can use `string`, `Object` or `function`. Object can be can have string as value for each item in it. But I would like to use function instead of string.

I have tried Object as functions list, but that is not working.

Comment: Use a custom filter with config options

Comment: @charlietfl - It will be custom filter only. I am writing it from scratch.  I guess I can use another property in scope to maintain list of filters and then use that filters list in function to filter each column. But I guess it will impact the performance. is there any better way to achieve the same output?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"will impact performance"*. The configuration options can be an argument of the custom filter

Comment: I mean, each filter will be for specific column only and if I use config object, it will be atleast 3 level loop - list of filters -> list of columns -> list of records... Records count may be less than 100 or more than 1000.

Comment: You probably should look at how other modules handle this. There are numerous table modules already available that you can learn from. Without a better understanding of exactly what it is you are trying to do it is hard to help. Some modules use declarative directives in html, others use config objects from scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104747/discussion-between-vikram-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Use `$scope.columnFilters = function(value, index, array) {}`

Comment: @georgeawg - This is not what I am looking for.